# Why is my data not going to my SQL database when i click the button?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, backend

```
 public partial class signupuser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // sign up button click event
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Response.Write("<script>alert('Testing');</script>");

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member_master_tbl(email, password, full_name, user_name, dob, account_status) VALUES(@email, @password, @full_name, @user_name, @dob, @account_status)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "Pending");

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Go to User Login to Login.');</script>");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code, I am currently developing an asp.net web app and I am using a SQL server and trying to make a sign up page. I want the input from the user to be stored into the database when i click the button. All that happens right now is I click the button and the page refreshes, but no data is added to the database. I am also not getting the alert box saying "Sign Up Successful" so something must be going wrong. Ideas?

Comment: Is it throwing an error? Is the connection string correct?

Comment: Did you try hardcoding safe values into each parameter? Is `dob` a `datetime` column? What format are you using? What value does `ExecuteNonQuery` return? You should enclose the connection in a `using` block. Can you perform a `select` using the same connection?

Comment: @AlexHall Yeah it should be correct, here it is. `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-RT4L03D\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
         Catalog=eWorkshopDB;Integrated Security=true"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Double check that connection string in the debugger inspecting `con.ConnectionString`.

Comment: @Americancain, did you try/check what I suggested?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I think that is the problem, now it's not even letting me launch the app on my browser and throwing an error, do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you if you don't explain anything about the error? It's like if I said "my car doesn't work, why?".

Comment: You need to do some work to isolate the problem. Confirm that your click handler is being reached by setting a breakpoint or adding logging. Confirm that your SqlCommand is executed without any exception. Confirm that the SQL is reaching your database, e.g. using a Profiler trace. Then cut and paste the SQL into a query window and confirm it does what you think it does. Right now the problem is much too broad for anyone to help.

Comment: If your app doesn't even start, you either have a deployment issue (e.g. a missing assembly, a service account that is locked out, or a million other things) or a configuration issue (e.g. web.config is missing, or not valid XML due to a missing closing tag or quote).

Answer (score 0):

It is useless to check if connection open immediately after creation. Connection should be open for the shortest time possible. Just before you execute command object. You have to remove this code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
```

But you are opening the connection before you create cmd. You should use connection this way:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    {
               var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member_master_tbl(email, password, full_name, user_name, dob, account_status) VALUES(@email, @password, @full_name, @user_name, @dob, @account_status)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "Pending");
             cmd.connection.Open();
             if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>= 1)
             {
                 
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Go to User Login 
            to Login.');</script>");
            }
       
    }
```

Comment: Lovely indentation. :P

Comment: When you use this syntax do you still  have SignUp  is succesfull?

Comment: @Sergey When i use that syntax i get an error from the top line from "con". I get error CS0136.

Comment: And you try Integrated Security=SSPI instead of Integrated Security =true. Sometimes it works.

Comment: Thanks everyone i got it figured out, it was my connection string at the top.

Comment: `You are opening the connection before you create cmd.`  That doesn't matter.  The connection only needs to be open when the command gets executed.

Comment: @Americancain [AddWithValue is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)